# Windows 11: Window moved to the left, cant drag it

Tags: windows

I uninstalled blender and in the process, it created a window and placed it all the way to the left of my screen:

[image: Bill Gates please]

I cant grab it to move it from anywhere, the "X" button on the window is taking all the visible space.

I can see it with alt-tab:

[image: Thank you windows programmers]

But I cant do anything else?!

Comment: Well no, I would like to drag the window back to visible aeria tho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible way is to press `Alt+Space`, then `M` and use arrow keys to move the window around. When you are finish just press space and the movement is released.

Comment: Oh damn. I didnt know that! (I tried it on another window tho, but it works like charm)

Comment: @ChristianidisVasileios, this work from the time of MS Windows 3.x (can't remember about 2.x) :)

Answer (score 1):

Okay I figured it out. I reduced the screen resolution and the window popped right in the visible space again:

[image: blender uninstall]

Comment: Very handy trick, will remember it :)